# R, cointegration, multivariate, co.ja(), johansen

Tags: r

I am new to R and cointegration so please have patience with me as I try to explain what it is that I am trying to do. I am trying to find cointegrated variables among 1500-2000 voltage variables in the west power system in Canada/US. THe frequency is hourly (common in power) and cointegrated combinations can be as few as N variables and a maximum of M variables.

I tried to use ca.jo but here are issues that I ran into:

1) ca.jo (Johansen) has a limit to the number of variables it can work with

2) ca.jo appears to force the first variable in the y(t) vector to be the dependent variable (see below).

Eigenvectors, normalised to first column: (These are the cointegration relations)

```
          V1.l2        V2.l2        V3.l2 
V1.l2    1.0000000    1.0000000    1.0000000   
V2.l2   -0.2597057   -2.3888060   -0.4181294   
V3.l2   -0.6443270   -0.6901678    0.5429844
```

As you can see ca.jo tries to find linear combinations of the 3 variables but by forcing the coefficient on the first variable (in this case V1) to be 1 (i.e. the dependent variable). My understanding was that ca.jo would try to find all combinations such that every variable is selected as a dependent variable. You can see the same treatment in the examples given in the documentation for ca.jo.

3) ca.jo does not appear to find linear combinations of fewer than the number of variables in the y(t) vector. So if there were 5 variables and 3 of them are cointegrated (i.e. V1 ~ V2 + V3) then ca.jo fails to find this combination. Perhaps I am not using ca.jo correctly but my expectation was that a cointegrated combination where V1 ~ V2 + V3 is the same as V1 ~ V2 + V3 + 0 x V4 + 0 x V5. In other words the coefficient of the variable that are NOT cointegrated should be zero and ca.jo should find this type of combination.

I would greatly appreciate some further insight as I am fairly new to R and cointegration and have spent the past 2 months teaching myself.

Thank you.

I have also posted on nabble:

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ca-jo-cointegration-multivariate-case-tc3469210.html

Comment: @User, you may want to consider asking this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Brandon Unfortunately, this is what was done 3 hours before posting here but the usefulness of stats.stackexchange.com, due to its lack of responsiveness, was questioned by the OP himself, in unfriendly terms (hence my downvote for this question, and my vote to close on stats.SE).

Comment: @chl, I can understand why this may be ignored on stats. It's highly specific to a particular package. Perhaps contacting the package author would be a better suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert, but since no one is responding, I'm going to try to take a stab at this one.. EDIT: I noticed that I just answered to a 4 year old question. Hopefully it might still be useful to others in the future.

Your general understanding is correct. I'm not going to go in great detail about the whole procedure but will try to give some general insight. The first thing that the Johansen procedure does is create a VECM out of the VAR model that best corresponds to the data (This is why you need the lag length for the VAR as input to the procedure as well). The procedure will then investigate the non-lagged component matrix of the VECM by looking at its rank: If the variables are not cointegrated then the rank of the matrix will not be significantly different from 0. A more intuitive way of understanding the johansen VECM equations is to notice the comparibility with the ADF procedure for each distinct row of the model.

Furthermore, The rank of the matrix is equal to the number of its eigenvalues (characteristic roots) that are different from zero. Each eigenvalue is associated with a different cointegrating vector, which
is equal to its corresponding eigenvector. Hence, An eigenvalue significantly different
from zero indicates a significant cointegrating vector. Significance of the vectors can be tested with two distinct statistics: The max statistic or the trace statistic. The trace test tests the null hypothesis of less than or equal to r cointegrating vectors against the alternative of more than r cointegrating vectors. In contrast, The maximum eigenvalue test tests the null hypothesis of r cointegrating vectors against the alternative of r + 1 cointegrating vectors.

Now for an example,

```
# We fit data to a VAR to obtain the optimal VAR length. Use SC information criterion to find optimal model.
varest <- VAR(yourData,p=1,type="const",lag.max=24, ic="SC")
# obtain lag length of VAR that best fits the data
lagLength <- max(2,varest$p)

# Perform Johansen procedure for cointegration
# Allow intercepts in the cointegrating vector: data without zero mean
# Use trace statistic (null hypothesis: number of cointegrating vectors <= r)
res <- ca.jo(yourData,type="trace",ecdet="const",K=lagLength,spec="longrun")

testStatistics <- res@teststat
criticalValues <- res@criticalValues

# chi^2. If testStatic for r<= 0 is greater than the corresponding criticalValue, then r<=0 is rejected and we have at least one cointegrating vector
# We use 90% confidence level to make our decision
if(testStatistics[length(testStatistics)] >= criticalValues[dim(criticalValues)[1],1])
{
  # Return eigenvector that has maximum eigenvalue. Note: we throw away the constant!!
  return(res@V[1:ncol(yourData),which.max(res@lambda)])
}
```

This piece of code checks if there is at least one cointegrating vector (r<=0) and then returns the vector with the highest cointegrating properties or in other words, the vector with the highest eigenvalue (lamda).

Regarding your question: the procedure does not "force" anything. It checks all combinations, that is why you have your 3 different vectors. It is my understanding that the method just scales/normalizes the vector to the first variable.

Regarding your other question: The procedure will calculate the vectors for which the residual has the strongest mean reverting / stationarity properties. If one or more of your variables does not contribute further to these properties then the component for this variable in the vector will indeed be 0. However, if the component value is not 0 then it means that "stronger" cointegration was found by including the extra variable in the model.

Furthermore, you can test test significance of your components. Johansen allows a researcher to test a hypothesis about one or more
coefficients in the cointegrating relationship by viewing the hypothesis as
a restriction on the non-lagged component matrix in the VECM. If there exist r cointegrating vectors, only these linear combinations or linear transformations of them, or combinations of the cointegrating vectors, will be stationary. However, I'm not aware on how to perform these extra checks in R.

Probably, the best way for you to proceed is to first test the combinations that contain a smaller number of variables. You then have the option to not add extra variables to these cointegrating subsets if you don't want to. But as already mentioned, adding other variables can potentially increase the cointegrating properties / stationarity of your residuals. It will depend on your requirements whether or not this is the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for an answer to this and I think I found one so I'm sharing with you hoping it's the right solution.

By using the johansen test you test for the ranks (number of cointegration vectors), and it also returns the eigenvectors, and the alphas and betas do build said vectors.
In theory if you reject r=0 and accept r=1 (value of r=0 > critical value and r=1 < critical value) you would search for the highest eigenvalue and from that build your vector. On this case, if the highest eigenvalue was the first, it would be V1*1+V2*(-0.26)+V3*(-0.64).
This would generate the cointegration residuals for these variables.

Again, I'm not 100%, but preety sure the above is how it works.

Nonetheless, you can always use the cajools function from the urca package to create a VECM automatically. You only need to feed it a cajo object and define the number of ranks (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/urca.pdf).

If someone could confirm / correct this, it would be appreciated.